# Recursively find number of lowercase letters in a string

Tags: python, string, recursion

I'm trying to recursively find the number of lowercase letters in a string with low and high indices that determine which part of the string needs to be considered: `def count_lowercase(s, low, high)`. My code stops going through the string once it hits an uppercase letter or a space because of `if s[count] == s[count].lower() and s[count] != ' '` but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get it to continue. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**My code**

```
def count_lowercase(s, low, high):
    def countfunc(s2=s[low: high+1], count=0):
        if count > high:
            return count
        else:
            if s[count] == s[count].lower() and s[count] != ' ':
                return countfunc(s2, count+1)
        return count
    return countfunc()
```

Comment: does it need to be recursive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of there being an uppercase or space is not handled, the count is immediately returned if it is not lowercase and is not a space.

Don't use the count as the index but keep it separate.

```
def count_lowercase(s, low, high):
    def countfunc(s2=s[low: high+1], count=0, index=0):
        if index > high:
            return count
        else:
            if s[index] == s[index].lower() and s[index] != ' ':
                return countfunc(s2, count+1, index+1)
            else:
                return countfunc(s2, count, index+1)
        return count
    return countfunc()
```

Think about if the code reaches a letter that is either a space or is uppercase, your if statement is false and isn't handled, going straight to `return count`. If you throw in an `else` for handling uppercases/spaces and still use count as an index, it will increase to go to the next index even when reaching an uppercase letter or a space.

Keep them separate and add the else!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to find lowercase letter in a portion of a string, why don't you follow this approach:

```
import re

def count_lowercase(s, low, high):
    return len(re.findall("[a-z]", s[max(0,low):min(high, len(s))]))
```

**Follow up**: if you cannot use any module:

```
def count_lowercase(s, low, high):
    s = s[max(0,low):min(high, len(s))].strip(" ")
    return sum([x==x.lower() for x in s])
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! Unfortunately I cannot use imports for the assignment but knowing that this is a possible solution is definitely helpful

Comment: @xander what you want if finding all the lower case characters in a portion of a string, correct?

Comment: yup! And the parameters in the outer function need to stay the same

Comment: @xander if only the outer function's parameters need to stay the same, my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69701472/5556651) should work